# Display the difference between 2 columns where multiple columns associated from dynamic matrix in ssrs 2008 r2

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDVK5.jpg)I have to show the data in the report just like above .. i need to get the difference of Medicaid 2017 value and Medicaid 2016 in Med diffrence 
commercial 2017 value and commercial 2016 in commercial difference column... note that 2016 & 2017 are dynamic values as year changes these will change..any pointers would really help? please see the attached images data & matrix

Appreciate your response.

Thank you!!!! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd2sW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Each row is going to be grouped by the salesperson so the only thing we need to detect for our calculation is the year.

> =SUM(IIF(Fields!Year.Value = "2016"), Fields!Medicaid.Value, 0)) - SUM(IIF(Fields!Year.Value = "2017"), Fields!Medicaid.Value, 0))

What this does is run the sum function through the dataset (with group filter). In sum we can nest the IIF logic to detect what the year field is in the dataset. If it is the year we are looking for, we return the value of the data (in this case the medicaid value). The end result is the sum of all values matching the date. Then we subtract that by the next year and there is your difference.

I know you want to keep this dynamic. You'll have to test your own solutions since I'm not sure how you will handle this in your data. Assuming at the very next year this will flip to current year and previous year, instead of hard coded year you would use:

> Now().Year  and Now().addYears(-1).Year

I think all this code should work but I did not test. You might have to confirm those VBNet DateTime functions. Just tried to get you an answer on my lunch break!

Comment: Adding another thought to the answer from @Lucky. If you can change your dataset and label the data currentYear, prevYear rather than the actual value, then you can hardcode those field names into the expression. if the columns themselves have to have the year shown, then add these values as additional columns in your dataset and set the column header to something like `=First(Fields!myCurrentYearLabelColumn.Value)`

Comment: Good idea, Alan! Now you got me thinking. Add prevYear and currentYear as parameters. That way you solve any ambiguity of what years are reported and the user can still access previous years data.

Comment: Thanks you for the responses.. however Fields!Medicaid.Value is directly coming...Medicaid is coming from the payer type column...so how do i modify the expression where  2 conditions match and display the value ..=SUM(IIF(Fields!SMN_Year.Value = Year(Now), Fields!Payer_Type.Value="Medicaid", Fields!Totals.Value ,0).. i try to write like this but this is not working for me

Comment: You're not using the IIF function right there, sai. IIF(expression, action when true, action when false). You can embed IIFs in each other like this: IIF(expression, IIF(expression, true, false), false)